# Para que serve o comando unless no Ruby

Tags: ruby, sintaxe

Alguém pode explicar como funciona esse comando `unless` no  Ruby?

```
ruby_is_ugly = false
puts "Ruby não é feio!" unless ruby_is_ugly
```

Tem com saída

```
"Ruby não é feio!"
```

Comment: Como assim? não vai dá nada na saída.

Comment: @M8n Copiei errado. Corrigi já. O certo é false, e não true como estava. Não tinha tomado café ainda. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em poucas palavras é um if ao contrario, onde executa o conteudo dentro da condicional caso a condição **não seja verdadeira**.

Exemplo:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

x = 1 
unless x == 2
   puts "x é diferente de 2"
 else
   puts "x é igual a 2"
end
```

Fonte:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm

Answer (score 1):

**unless** é equivalente a utilizar if not, utilizar unless ou **if not** (if !condition) é uma preferencia pessoal.
Eu pessoalmente uso **unless** quando não é necessário um **else**.

Comment: Isso já não havia sido dito na outra resposta? Não entendi o que você quis completar com a sua.

Comment: @Andeson Carlos Woss, mais ou menos, só quis expressar de uma forma um pouco diferente. O que tem de errado na resposta?

Comment: Em questão de conteúdo, poderia detalhar mais e dar exemplos, mas só me referi ao ponto em que considero desnecessário uma nova resposta que acrescenta em nada à discussão. Tudo o que você disse foi dito na outra resposta. Se você editar sua resposta e adicionar algo que acrescente em conteúdo, ok. Aliás, não fui eu que negativou a resposta.

Comment: Entendi, é que antes de responder,  mesmo a duvida sendo simples, eu fiz uma boa pesquisa no SO em inglês e me pareceu fazer sentido adicionar uma explicação, mesmo parecendo redundante.

Comment: Você pode deixar, se quiser. Esta é apenas a minha opinião. Se você acha que é válido, deixe.